# The pythonic way to construct a multimethod setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, getter-setter

We can use a `@property` to construct a getter and setter. This is a short example how we can do this:

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            self.__x = 0
        elif x > 100:
            self.__x = 100
        else:
            self.__x = x
```

My case seems to be more complicated.

```py
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        self.x1()
        self.x2()
        self.x3()

    def x1(self):
        self.__x1 = self.__x + 1
        return self.__x1

    def x2(self):
        self.__x2 = self.__x1 + 2
        return self.__x2

    def x3(self):
        self.__x3 = self.__x2 + 3
        return self.__x3


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(3)
    print(a.x3)
```

Methods `x1`, `x2` and `x3` are oversimplified. The `self.__x3` variable is set only once, when the `__init__` method is called. Now, I need a getter method to get `self.__x3` by calling `a.x3`. How to achieve that in the pythonic way?

Comment: I'd suggest break your problem down into a generic one as there's a lot of information not really related to it, personally I wasn't really able to understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide your entire class - it is very hard to understand what your problem is.

Comment: I've simplified the description and added the considered class.

Comment: Without a motivation here, I'm not sure why you'd even write `x1`/`x2`/`x3` as mutating methods when only `__init__` uses them, when you could just write internal helper functions (e.g. `_x1`/`_x2`/`_x3` for `__init__`'s use) and use regular non-mutating properties for `x1`/`x2`/`x3` (for public use). This stinks of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040). Even if this is valid, should the outside user's use of `x3` modify `__x3`, or just return it?

Comment: @ShadowRanger you're right. I considered `_` before method's names. I asked about it before editing my post to be more understandable. And no, `__x3` cannot be modify. Now I see that your solution (non-mutating properties for `xN`) is what I need.

Comment: @Benek: Well, I answered in such a way that it covers that use case, as well as the more insane use cases (that *might* be justifiable if the non-mutating code path is complex and shared between init helper and getter property). In your motivating case, the `__init__` helper path's return is never used, so you probably don't want this, but it might be helpful for understanding properties better in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting an answer based on the assumption that you want the `__x#` variables modified only during `__init__`, and never again, but also want the accessors to follow the same code path (possibly because the read is also programmatically complex):

In this case, you can have the implementing function take an additional, defaulted argument. When accessed in attribute form, it will receive the defaulted argument, but if the `fget` member of the property is explicitly accessed, it can be called with the non-default argument. A simple example addressing `x1` only:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        # Access the property itself off the class, bypassing execution,
        # then call it directly with the non-default argument
        type(self).x1.fget(self, True)

    @property
    def x1(self, doset=False):
        if doset:
            self.__x1 = self.__x + 1
        return self.__x1
```

Alternatively, to simplify the usage in `__init__`, you can use a separate name for the underlying function vs. the `property` to achieve the same effect:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        # Call the implementing function directly with the non-default argument
        self._x1(True)

    # Implementing function named with single underscore prefix to indicate it's
    # for internal/protected use only
    def _x1(self, doset=False):
        if doset:
            self.__x1 = self.__x + 1
        return self.__x1
    # Define property x1 based on x1 for outside use
    x1 = property(_x1)
```

Of course, if you don't have a complicated getter path, then the real solution is to separate `_x1` from `x1` completely, where `_x1` is pure setter helper function for `__init__`, and `x1` is pure getter:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.__x = x
        # Call the init helper
        self._init_x1()

    # Implementing function named with single underscore prefix to indicate it's
    # for internal/protected use only
    def _init_x1(self):
        self.__x1 = self.__x + 1

    @property:
    def x1(self):
        return self.__x1
```

**To be clear, only the last of these is "Pythonic"** in any meaningful sense. The second option has some limited use cases (where you have a function that demands existence, and is highly configurable, but has a reasonable set of defaults that a `property` could use), but in that case, it's usually a function that has public utility just like the `property`. Option #1 is the least Pythonic, as it's inconvenient to use (needing to elevate to the class type, extract the `fget` member, and explicitly pass `self`), and makes it quite clear that there is no expected use case outside of `__init__` (because it's such a pain to use that no one would bother).